# Can't understand a property of delta function and convolution

Tags: distribution-theory, convolution, fourier-transform, dirac-delta

I am reading a book and I couldn't understand an equality. Actually, I realized I don't really understand the property of convolution with Dirac's delta function. I hope you can help me.
I know the property:
$(\delta*f)(t)=f(t)$

First question, is it correct to write:

$\delta(t)*f(t)=f(t)$

Does this also work for a shifted $\delta$ function?

Here is what I am trying to understand from the book:
$$\rho_p(x)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\rho(x-kp)=_{(\#)}\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(x-kp)*\rho(x)=\left(\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(x-kp)\right)*\rho(x)$$

I can't understand the equality I marked with a $\#$.

In case you need to know:

$\rho(x)$- is a function describing the density of electrons.

$p$- is the period of the the new function (they are periodizing the function $\rho$)

Thanks.

Comment: **Is it correct to write $\delta(t)*f(t)=f(t)$?** No.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to be aware of the following property,

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(x) f(x) \ dx = f(0),$$

which implies that,

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(x-a) f(x) \ dx = f(a).$$

Note that the $\delta$ function forces the integration variable $x$ to equal $a$ in the above example.

---

The definition of convolution is,

$$ (F(\tau)*G(\tau))(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F(\tau) G(t-\tau) \ d\tau,$$

We will apply this definition to your expression. In this case $F(\tau) = \delta(\tau-kp)$ and $G(\tau)=f(\tau)$.
$$(F*G)(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  F(\tau) G(x-\tau) \ d\tau =  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  \delta(\tau-kp) f(x-\tau) \ d\tau = f(x-kp),$$

Where in the last equality we used the property of the delta function to collapse the integral and force the integration variable $\tau$ to equal $kp$.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I will be grateful if you can give me more details about what exactly you did there. Sorry, but this topic is quite new to me, and I tried to understand this by my self without success.

Comment: Sure I can provide more details. Do you have any familiarity with delta functions?

Comment: I know it's definition and the basic property that it's integral over R is 1. I don't really know how to deal with this multiplication inside the integral. In addition, I'm not really sure how to change and use the convolution with it and I don't understand how to change variables as you did. I see that in the definition of convolution both of the functions have the same variable, but some how you managed to use the convolution while they are not with exactly the same variable.

Comment: Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Wow thank you very much, It's much clearer now.